# Convertir archivo SMIL a JSON

Tags: python, json, xml, lista, método

En este programa manejamos un fichero .smil y lo queremos convertir en Json durante su ejecución. El programa funciona tal y como debe en todos los métodos pero me muestra la misma salida que cuando imprimía por el terminal el fichero .smil por lo tanto creo que mi método to_json no deber estar haciendo bien su función.

```
import sys
import json
from xml.sax import make_parser
from smallsmilhandler import SmallSMILHandler
from urllib.request import urlretrieve


class KaraokeLocal():

    def __init__(self, fich):
        parser = make_parser()
        cHandler = SmallSMILHandler()
        parser.setContentHandler(cHandler)
        parser.parse(open(file_smil))
        self.my_file = cHandler.get_tags()

    def __str__(self):
        archivo_smil = []
        for linea in self.my_file:
            lista_final = []
            etiqueta = linea[0]
            lista_final.append(etiqueta)
            for atributo, valor in linea[1].items():
                lista_final.append (atributo + "=" + '"' + valor + '"')   
            lista_final = '\t'.join(lista_final)
            archivo_smil.append(lista_final + '\n')
        print(archivo_smil)

    def to_json(self,fjson):
        with open(file_json, "w"):
            json.dumps(self.my_file)

    def do_local(self):
        for linea in self.my_file:
                for atributo, valor in linea[1].items():
                    if valor[:7] == "http://":
                        name_local = valor.split('/')[-1]
                        urlretrieve(valor, name_local)
                        print("Descargando %s..." % valor)    

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        file_smil = sys.argv[1]
        file_json = sys.argv[1].replace(".smil", ".json")
        file_karaoke = KaraokeLocal(file_smil)
        file_karaoke.__str__()
        file_karaoke.to_json(file_json)
        file_karaoke.do_local()
        file_karaoke.to_json('.json')                
        file_karaoke.__str__()



    except IndexError:

        sys.exit("Usage:python3 karaoke.py file.smil")
```

Añado la salida que obtengo en el terminal:

```
['root-layout\twidth="248"\theight="300"\tbackground-color="blue"\n',     'region\tid="a"\ttop="20"\tbottom=""\tleft="64"\tright=""\n', 'region\tid="b"\ttop="120"\tbottom=""\tleft="20"\tright=""\n', 'region\tid="text_area"\ttop="100"\tbottom=""\tleft="20"\tright=""\n', 'img\tsrc="http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.jpg"\tregion="a"\tbegin="2s"\tdur="36s"\n', 'img\tsrc="http://www.content-networking.com/smil/earthrise.jpg"\tregion="b"\tbegin="12s"\tdur=""\n', 'audio\tsrc="http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.wav"\tbegin="1s"\tdur=""\n', 'textstream\tsrc="http://gsyc.es/~grex/letra.rt"\tregion="text_area"\n', 'audio\tsrc="cancion.ogg"\tbegin="4s"\tdur=""\n']


Descargando http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.jpg...
Descargando http://www.content-networking.com/smil/earthrise.jpg...
Descargando http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.wav...
Descargando http://gsyc.es/~grex/letra.rt...


['root-layout\twidth="248"\theight="300"\tbackground-color="blue"\n', 'region\tid="a"\ttop="20"\tbottom=""\tleft="64"\tright=""\n', 'region\tid="b"\ttop="120"\tbottom=""\tleft="20"\tright=""\n', 'region\tid="text_area"\ttop="100"\tbottom=""\tleft="20"\tright=""\n', 'img\tsrc="http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.jpg"\tregion="a"\tbegin="2s"\tdur="36s"\n', 'img\tsrc="http://www.content-networking.com/smil/earthrise.jpg"\tregion="b"\tbegin="12s"\tdur=""\n', 'audio\tsrc="http://www.content-networking.com/smil/hello.wav"\tbegin="1s"\tdur=""\n', 'textstream\tsrc="http://gsyc.es/~grex/letra.rt"\tregion="text_area"\n', 'audio\tsrc="cancion.ogg"\tbegin="4s"\tdur=""\n']
```

Comment: No se entiende para qué es la función `__str__()`, pero en todo caso no es un nombre apropiado. Si una clase Python implementa `__str__()`  se espera que retorne una cadena que represente el contenido del objeto de alguna forma amigable para el `print()`, pero no que imprima nada. O bien haces que simplemente retorne la cadena `archivo_smil` en lugar de imprimirla, o le cambias el nombre a la función (por ejemplo `imprime()`. Si eliges la primera opción, desde el programa principal harías `print(file_karaoke)`, en lugar de `file_karaoke.__str__()`.

Comment: La funcion `to_json()` no usa el parámetro que recibe (`fjson`), sino en cambio otro no declarado `file_json` (que funciona porque es una variable global creada en el programa principal, pero no está bien).

Comment: Por otro lado, el formato JSON es prácticamente igual al que Python usa para sus listas y diccionarios, por lo que no es raro que el volcado a JSON sea muy parecido (si no idéntico) a lo que obtienes imprimiendo directamente la variable `my_file` por pantalla. A menos que estés diciendo que lo que obtienes en el fichero .json es lo mismo que lo que había en el fichero .smil, en cuyo caso sí que habría algo mal.